# Python Regex Extract Width x Depth x Height

Tags: python, regex, pandas, extract

I am trying to extract the physical dimensions of items from a column "Description" in a df to create a new column with it.

Dimensions usually appear in this format (120x80x100) in the middle of long descriptions like:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit 120x80x100 ed do eiusmod tempor...
```

But sometimes have spaces between:

```
120 x 80 x 100
```

Or don't have height:

```
120x80
120 x 80
```

Any help?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe https://regex101.com/r/v52Cwd/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/rS27Vf/1), `\d+\s*x\s*\d+(?:\s*x\s*\d+)?`

**Explanation:**

- `\d+`: One or more digits
- `\s*`: Zero or more whitespace characters
- `x`: Literal, `x`
- `(?:\s*x\s*\d+)?`: Optional non-capturing group

If you want the numbers to be of one to three digits, replace `\d+` with `\d{1,3}` as shown in the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/GjwkRx/1), `\d{1,3}\s*x\s*\d{1,3}(?:\s*x\s*\d{1,3})?`.

If your code requires you to use a group, do it as follows:

```
(\d{1,3}\s*x\s*\d{1,3}(?:\s*x\s*\d{1,3})?)
```

Comment: My apologies @Arvind, I made a mistake copy pasting.

I mean, when I put your regex in my code I have this error: "ValueError: pattern contains no capture groups"

My code:
`df.Description.str.extract(r\d+\s*x\s*\d+(?:\s*x\s*\d+)?')`

Do you know why?
Thanks again

Comment: @AndréBatista - No worries. If your code requires you to use a group, put the regex inside a parenthesis e.g. `df.Description.str.extract(r'(\d{1,3}\s*x\s*\d{1,3}(?:\s*x\s*\d{1,3})?)')`. [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SkRJ7I/1).

Comment: Perfect! It's working! Thanks a lot @Arvind

Answer (score 2):

We can try using a `re.findall` approach with a regex pattern covering all possible dimension formats:

```py
inp = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit 1. 20x80x100 ed do 120 x 80 x 100 eiusmod 120x80 tempor...'
dims = re.findall(r'\d+(?:\s*x\s*\d+){1,2}', inp)
print(dims)  # ['120x80x100', '120 x 80 x 100', '120x80']
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
It works perfectly, but I need to extract from the item description column that has more than 10000 rows and create a new column with the items dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
\d+(\s?x\s?\d+){1,2}
```