# Python Regex including Comma and Dot

Tags: python, regex, pandas, extract

I am trying to extract the physical dimensions of items from a column and at the moment my regex is working fine. I was helped [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68547735/python-regex-extract-width-x-depth-x-height)

The only issue now is that the regex does not include dots or commas

My current regex:

```
'(\d{1,3}\s*[xX*]\s*\d{1,3}(?:\s*[xX*]\s*\d{1,3})?)'
```

It's working fine for:

```
120 x 80 x 100
120x80
120 x 80
120X80x100
120*80 * 100
```

Now I need it to also look for [,.]

```
120,3x80,9x1003
120.3x80.9
```

Any help?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
r'\b(\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*\s*[xX*]\s*\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*(?:\s*[xX*]\s*\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*)?)\b'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3JH4BI/2).

*Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(` - Group 1:

  - `\d+` - one or more digits
  - `(?:[.,]\d+)*` - zero or more occurrences of `.` or `,` and one or more digits
  - `\s*[xX*]\s*` - `x`, `X` or `*` enclosed with zero or more whitespaces
  - `\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*` - one or more digits and then zero or more occurrences of `.` or `,` and one or more digits
  - `(?:\s*[xX*]\s*\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*)?` - an optional occurrence of `x`, `X` or `*` enclosed with zero or more whitespaces, followed with one or more digits and then zero or more occurrences of `.` or `,` and one or more digits
- `)` - end of Group 1
- `\b` - a word boundary